# How to write code for Add a calculator to Wix website?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a new website using Wix.com and require assistance with the online payment system. I would like a calculator to be added to my website. This calculator must be able to conduct a word count of documents that clients will upload onto the website, and then based on a per word fee, will need to calculate what the total cost will be for the client should they wish to proceed with purchasing our proofreading/editing services. Ideally, once the total price/quote is calculated, clients should then be able to proceed with completing their order online and making payment online via Paypal

Comment: not now ...because i have no idea about this code ...if you have so please reply me soon...

Answer (score 1):

A similar question arose recently when it was necessary to make a similar calculator on Wix. Now he has several built-in applications for creating calculators and accepting payments. They are pretty good, but in some places they were not very suitable due to the lack of necessary facilities.

The ability to create a simple calculator with accepting PayPal payments, sending email and phone, was found in [uCalc](https://ucalc.pro/en/help/integration/wix). This is not a built-in application, but quite fit my tasks. Insertion on Wix is ​​done through [Wix source code](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-code-working-with-the-html-element). In it, by the way, there is the possibility of downloading files by clients and sending them in the order. This is the easiest way to create such a calculator.

Otherwise, knowledge of at least PHP and JavaScript is necessary to create your calculator, put it on a third-party hosting (since Wix does not have PHP) and link it through Wix, for example, through an [Wix API](https://www.wix.com/code/home/api). But it will take a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Wix currently does not have the kind of component you are looking for. To accomplish what you want, you would need to write the code yourself, and then [embed](http://www.wix.com/app-market/html-iframe-embed/features) it as an iFrame or make it a Wix App. You can find more info [here](http://www.wix.com/app-market/html-iframe-embed/features)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a calculator to Wix is ​​solved by embedded applications. However, not all of them contain the necessary functionality and most of them are just a regular web form, which is not always possible to customize to solve your problems.

The easiest way to create a calculator on Wix is ​​to use a third-party service, for example, the builder of [calculators and forms stepFORM](https://stepform.io). It is added similarly to other widgets through Wix code. The service allows you to create a calculator of varying complexity in visual mode.

If you need something more complex, that is, the Wix API, but it is quite complicated and long.